# writing or reading to NSUserDefaults while dismissing viewcontroller crashes with Exc bad access

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

While dismissing the modalView I save the changes in `NSUserDefaults`and synchronize them in the method `"saveinUserDeaultsObjects"`.

Now, repeating this process twice crashes the with exc bad access.(i.e presenting and dismissing).

But, if I dismiss `viewcontroller` after 1 sec delay using perform selector the app works fine.

What can I infer from this ? - I think writing to `NSUserdefaults` taking some time while the passed object is released.
If it is the case how to handle such situations ?

```
- (void)dismissViewController {
    [Utils  saveinUserDeaultsObjects:self.sortVlaue Forkey:@"SortByValue"];
    [Utils  saveinUserDeaultsObjects:self.state Forkey:@"State"];
    [Utils  saveinUserDeaultsObjects:self.topic Forkey:@"AOPString"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Thank You.

**Update**

```
+ (void)saveinUserDeaultsObjects:(NSString )valueObject Forkey:(NSString)key { 
    //NSLog(@"SaveUseref for key: %@ object: %@",key, valueObject); 

    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
   [userPreferences setObject:valueObject forKey:key]; 
   [userPreferences synchronize]; 
}
```

**Update 2**

```
+ (NSString )retriveFromUserDeaultsStringForkey:(NSString)key {
    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    NSString *value = nil; 
    if (userPreferences) value = (NSString *)[userPreferences objectForKey:key]; 
    return value; 
}
```

the crash it ocassionally shows is at reading the "value" object above. Mostly it is EXC bad access and the malloc stack trace is:

```
12: 0x1c0b85f in -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSourceSynchronizer createPlistFromDisk] 
13: 0x1bdfc56 in -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSourceSynchronizer synchronizeAlready]
```

Comment: We need to see the code for saveinUserDefaults probably

Comment: + (void)saveinUserDeaultsObjects:(NSString *)valueObject Forkey:(NSString*)key{
    //NSLog(@"SaveUseref for key: %@ object: %@",key, valueObject);

    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userPreferences setObject:valueObject forKey:key];
    [userPreferences synchronize];
    

}

Comment: Try putting an exception breakpoint in and causing it to crash. then report back. It should show you which line is causing the crash.

Comment: + (NSString *)retriveFromUserDeaultsStringForkey:(NSString*)key {
    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *value = nil;
    
    if (userPreferences)
        value = (NSString *)[userPreferences objectForKey:key];
    
    return value;
}  the crash it ocassionally shows is at reading the "value" object above. mostly it is EXC bad access and the malloc stack trace is:   12: 0x1c0b85f in -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSourceSynchronizer createPlistFromDisk]
   13: 0x1bdfc56 in -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSourceSynchronizer synchronizeAlready

Comment: You have a typo in **self.sortVlaue** and if you arent using the completion: part of the `dismissViewController`, set it to `nil`.